# Was the option to get email updates for answers on a specific question removed?

Tags: support, email-notification

IIRC there was up to recently an option to "subscribe" to specific questions that interest you, and get email notification on these on a per-question basis. Was this option removed?

Comment: No such option has ever existed. There is an RSS feed at the bottom of every question, though.

Comment: The only thing you can subscribe to are tags.

Comment: @animuson - I understand what happened. When I asked a new question, I got presented with an option to subscribe via email. I thought this dialog was specific to this question alone, while actually what it did was change the site/network-wide email setting.

Answer (score 0):

According to @animuson's comment above, no such option ever existed. Maybe I'm wishful thinking.